# Calculate median - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Can somebody explain to me how this query below works?
It's a query to calculate a median Latitude from the table. I get tired of understanding this and still, I can't.

```
SELECT * 
FROM station as st
where (
    select count(LAT_N) 
    from station 
    where LAT_N < st.LAT_N
) = (
    select count(LAT_N) 
    from STATION where LAT_N > st.LAT_N
);
```

Comment: For each row in station, it is trying to do a subquery finding a count of rows with a lower latitude and a subquery finding a count rows with a higher latitude and returning the rows where the two counts are equal.  This is not a correct way to find a median, since it will return nothing if there are two rows in the middle with different latitudes.

Comment: It doesn't handle duplicates well. E.g. if all stations has the same LAT_N value, all rows will be returned. And if you then add a new, different value, no rows at all will be returned. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c7bd100048b555ceb8f7d2a9d419e8a4

Answer (score 1):

The median is the middle value in a collection, which means there are as many values above it as below.

So for each row in the table, the first subquery counts the number of rows where `LAT_N` is lower than in the current row, and the second counts the number of rows where it's higher. Then it only returns the rows where these counts are the same.

Note that this won't work in many situations. The simplest example is when there are an even number of distinct values:

```
1
2
3
4
```

The median should be `2.5` (the mean of the two middle values), which doesn't exist in the table.

Another case is when there are duplicate values:

```
1
1
2
```

the median should be `1`. But the count of lower values is `0`, while the count of higher values is `1`, so they won't be equal.

Comment: You're right. I changed the example.

Answer (score 0):

Oh that's some clever code! It's got a bug, but here's what it's trying to do.

We define median as the value(s) that have the same number of values greater and less than them. So here's the query in pseudocode:

```html
for each station in st:
    compute number of stations with latitude greater than the current station's latitude
    compute number of stations with latitude less than the current station's latitude
    If these two values are equal, include it in the result.
```

---

Bug:

For tables with an even number of distinct values, the median should be defined as the mean of the two middle values. This code doesn't handle that.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help, I got it due to your pseudocode. I will try to modify it to compute the median with an even number of values.